# Tuckey correction for planned contrasts with emmeans and pairs() in R

Tags: r, anova, posthoc, emmeans

I have a mixed design with 1 between factor (Group: ASD, CTR) and three within factors (Time: pre, post; Trustee: good, bad; Step: 1,2,3,4,5).

I performed a mixed model anova (type III) with aov_car:

```
anova <- aov_car(rating ~ time*trustee*step*group + Error(id/time*trustee*step), data = datatemp, anova_table = list(es = "ges"))
```

I got a significant three way interaction: Time * Trustee * Step

I want to decompose the interaction by doing planned contrasts for time (I am just interested in the contrasts between pre and post for the different trustees  and steps).

This is the cose I used:

```
trustee_time_step <- emmeans(anova, ~ time | trustee | step) 
pairs(trustee_time_step)
```

results for comparison with time

[image]

By default, pairs() should perform a Tuckey correction.
However no correction is done on the contrasts.

The Tuckey correction appears only if I use step to divide my contrasts:

```
step_time_trustee <- emmeans(anova,  ~ step | trustee | time) 
pairs(step_time_trustee)
```

results for comparison with step

[image]

I guess it is because Time has just two levels (each contrast is just post vs. pre) while step has 5 levels (see "tukey method for comparing a family of 5 estimates" at the end of the picture).

So this is my question: why pairs() does not apply correction in the first case? Even if post vs. pre is just one contrast, it is done 10 times (one for each combination of trustee and step) and thus it should be corrected in my opinion.
What should I do? Shall I correct them manually? And if yes, how?

I am very confused about this matter, and I don't want to report uncorrected results if this is not "statistically good".

I hope my question is clear enough.
Thank you for the help!

Comment: I'm not sure if your question is off-topic here, but since it seems to be more about statistics than programming you might have better luck asking the stats experts at [stats.se]

Comment: I tried here because maybe somebody knew about the package and had an explanation but I will try also in Cross Validated! Thank you for your suggestion!